# How do you keep a listview row highlighted after its activated?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application I'm working on that uses listviews. When you select a row from the list view it becomes highlighted, however when I double click on it to activate the listview item it is no longer highlighted. How would I get the listview item to stay highlighted upon activation, is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Double-clicking an item in a ListView does not unselect it.  Clearly repro code is required to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you are somehow losing focus from the control.  *If* that logic is correct, then you can set the listview's `.HideSelection = False` property to retain the visual selection when the control loses focus.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. The selections are being cleared.